# iOS native Facebook share, link preview not working?

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch

I need to share the URL to Facebook from my app, and I am using SLComposeViewController for same. Here is the code I am using :-

```
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
    SLComposeViewController *facebookController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [facebookController setInitialText:text];
    [facebookController addURL:url];    
    [facebookController addImage:image];
    [controller presentViewController:facebookController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Here is the URL, I am using :-

http://www.erosnow.com/#!/movie/watch/1004607/ferrari-ki-sawaari/6095229/ferrari-ki-sawaari

The problem is, it doesn't show link preview. But when I copy paste the URL in Facebook "Whats your mind" segment, it do show the link preview. Any help

Comment: did you declare `url` as `NSUrl`, or `NSString`?   (in my case, passing `NSString` instead of `NSUrl` caused the issue you describe, but I was using `UIActivityViewController`, not `SLComposeViewController`)

Comment: Yes, I declare my URL as NSUrl.